# Heteroskedastic Logit Model in R with error "Error in if (abs(chi2) < tol) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" (in package mlogit)

Tags: multinomial

I am running multinominal logit model, following the steps in: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/c4.relaxiid.html

I am analyzing the choice made by firms among 35 alternatives. Each firm faces 35 alternatives and choose one. My data set is quite large, including 97176 observations. When I run standard mlogit (ml.FDI), it works but when I run heteroskedastic logit model (hl.FDI) it has the error " Error in if (abs(chi2) < tol) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
I check and there is no missing value. I also read some answers about similar error such as here: [R mlogit() function: Error in if (abs(x - oldx) < ftol) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840042/r-mlogit-function-error-in-if-absx-oldx-ftol-missing-value-where)

However, I am not sure if my error is the same because my error is:"Error in if (abs(chi2) < tol)..."
My other question is whether we always need dfidx to trasnform data before running mlogit.

I am beginner of R and really look forward to your help. Thank you in advance.
My dataset looks like:

````
trimmed_data_sub2 <-
  structure(
    list(
      firm_id = c(
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108582716,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870,
        108594870
      ),
      alt = c(
        "Ninhbinh_province",
        "Travinh_province",
        "Vinhlong_province",
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Phutho_province",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Thuathienhue_province",
        "Longan_province",
        "Nghean_province",
        "Camau_province",
        "Quangninh_province",
        "Dongnai_province",
        "Binhthuan_province",
        "Tayninh_province",
        "Namdinh_province",
        "Quangngai_province",
        "Thainguyen_province",
        "Binhduong_province",
        "Thanhhoa_province",
        "Hungyen_province",
        "Hanam_province",
        "Haiduong_province",
        "Hatinh_province",
        "Tuyenquang_province",
        "Danang_city",
        "Haugiang_province",
        "Baria-vungtau_province",
        "Thaibinh_province",
        "Vinhphuc_province",
        "Bacninh_province",
        "Backan_province",
        "Quangnam_province",
        "Hochiminh_city",
        "Binhphuoc_province",
        "Bacgiang_province",
        "Longan_province",
        "Bacgiang_province",
        "Dongnai_province",
        "Thuathienhue_province",
        "Haugiang_province",
        "Hungyen_province",
        "Baria-vungtau_province",
        "Quangninh_province",
        "Danang_city",
        "Hatinh_province",
        "Thanhhoa_province",
        "Binhduong_province",
        "Bacninh_province",
        "Hochiminh_city",
        "Haiphong_city",
        "Quangnam_province",
        "Backan_province",
        "Thainguyen_province",
        "Hanam_province",
        "Phutho_province",
        "Vinhphuc_province",
        "Vinhlong_province",
        "Hanoi_city",
        "Travinh_province",
        "Ninhbinh_province",
        "Quangngai_province",
        "Tayninh_province",
        "Thaibinh_province",
        "Nghean_province",
        "Haiduong_province",
        "Namdinh_province",
        "Binhthuan_province",
        "Camau_province",
        "Tuyenquang_province",
        "Binhphuoc_province"
      ),
      choice = c(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ),
      year_operation = c(
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019,
        2019
      ),
      sector = c(
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA",
        "SA"
      ),
      technology = c(
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low",
        "Low"
      ),
      logMAinside1 = c(
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178,
        8.2224178
      ),
      logMAoutside1 = c(
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506,
        8.1201506
      ),
      logSAinside1 = c(
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056,
        7.7692056
      ),
      logSAoutside1 = c(
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966,
        7.8650966
      ),
      logseaport3 = c(
        4.8283138,
        4.89784,
        4.9126549,
        1.4350846,
        5.3082676,
        4.8202815,
        4.6249728,
        4.0055132,
        5.9506426,
        5.7462034,
        3.8501475,
        3.4594662,
        5.1704841,
        4.7361984,
        4.4875121,
        4.9972124,
        5.1817837,
        3.5973122,
        5.2522736,
        4.5315237,
        4.8520303,
        3.8110971,
        6.0776424,
        5.556828,
        2.587764,
        5.3706379,
        4.2297492,
        4.2456341,
        5.1239638,
        4.5549288,
        4.7361984,
        4.383276,
        2.6390574,
        4.6634393,
        4.5890408,
        4.0055132,
        4.5890408,
        3.4594662,
        4.6249728,
        5.3706379,
        4.5315237,
        4.2297492,
        3.8501475,
        2.587764,
        6.0776424,
        5.2522736,
        3.5973122,
        4.5549288,
        2.6390574,
        1.4350846,
        4.383276,
        4.7361984,
        5.1817837,
        4.8520303,
        5.3082676,
        5.1239638,
        4.9126549,
        4.8202815,
        4.89784,
        4.8283138,
        4.9972124,
        4.7361984,
        4.2456341,
        5.9506426,
        3.8110971,
        4.4875121,
        5.1704841,
        5.7462034,
        5.556828,
        4.6634393
      ),
      logpop = c(
        6.5539336,
        6.0980744,
        6.5352411,
        7.161622,
        5.9839363,
        7.7137847,
        5.46806,
        5.811141,
        5.2574954,
        5.4638319,
        5.32301,
        6.2653012,
        5.0498562,
        5.6347895,
        7.0130157,
        5.5093884,
        5.8861041,
        6.6883545,
        5.768321,
        7.1530519,
        6.84375,
        6.9874902,
        5.3612924,
        4.8903489,
        6.7345915,
        6.1717005,
        6.331502,
        7.029973,
        6.7844572,
        7.3238306,
        4.2046928,
        4.9558272,
        8.3359108,
        4.9558272,
        6.0730443,
        5.811141,
        6.0730443,
        6.2653012,
        5.46806,
        6.1717005,
        7.1530519,
        6.331502,
        5.32301,
        6.7345915,
        5.3612924,
        5.768321,
        6.6883545,
        7.3238306,
        8.3359108,
        7.161622,
        4.9558272,
        4.2046928,
        5.8861041,
        6.84375,
        5.9839363,
        6.7844572,
        6.5352411,
        7.7137847,
        6.0980744,
        6.5539336,
        5.5093884,
        5.6347895,
        7.029973,
        5.2574954,
        6.9874902,
        7.0130157,
        5.0498562,
        5.4638319,
        4.8903489,
        4.9558272
      ),
      logopenness = c(
        5.0262208,
        3.1784184,
        3.5308795,
        5.5514636,
        4.7599664,
        4.702239,
        4.2329168,
        5.3210664,
        3.3081558,
        4.0027852,
        4.2263217,
        5.5089636,
        3.8159115,
        5.4272904,
        4.6440415,
        3.8801143,
        6.7543707,
        5.8385348,
        4.5135665,
        5.4823933,
        5.30164,
        5.6670299,
        4.708425,
        2.4108267,
        4.3072119,
        4.5786986,
        4.4369946,
        4.5747805,
        5.3757849,
        6.6909885,-1.7439516,
        4.1683974,
        5.0551434,
        4.9517002,
        5.6537271,
        5.3210664,
        5.6537271,
        5.5089636,
        4.2329168,
        4.5786986,
        5.4823933,
        4.4369946,
        4.2263217,
        4.3072119,
        4.708425,
        4.5135665,
        5.8385348,
        6.6909885,
        5.0551434,
        5.5514636,
        4.1683974,-1.7439516,
        6.7543707,
        5.30164,
        4.7599664,
        5.3757849,
        3.5308795,
        4.702239,
        3.1784184,
        5.0262208,
        3.8801143,
        5.4272904,
        4.5747805,
        3.3081558,
        5.6670299,
        4.6440415,
        3.8159115,
        4.0027852,
        2.4108267,
        4.9517002
      ),
      logPCI = c(
        4.1679049,
        4.1463041,
        4.2668962,
        4.230186,
        4.1826606,
        4.2312036,
        4.1972017,
        4.2314944,
        4.1993051,
        4.1604443,
        4.2959237,
        4.186924,
        4.1794515,
        4.2054386,
        4.1757708,
        4.1640263,
        4.2152338,
        4.2103481,
        4.184185,
        4.1526136,
        4.1754637,
        4.1565366,
        4.1814394,
        4.1763854,
        4.2506356,
        4.161068,
        4.2040954,
        4.1802163,
        4.2009544,
        4.2597179,
        4.139955,
        4.2401752,
        4.207078,
        4.1305156,
        4.1662002,
        4.2314944,
        4.1662002,
        4.186924,
        4.1972017,
        4.161068,
        4.1526136,
        4.2040954,
        4.2959237,
        4.2506356,
        4.1814394,
        4.184185,
        4.2103481,
        4.2597179,
        4.207078,
        4.230186,
        4.2401752,
        4.139955,
        4.2152338,
        4.1754637,
        4.1826606,
        4.2009544,
        4.2668962,
        4.2312036,
        4.1463041,
        4.1679049,
        4.1640263,
        4.2054386,
        4.1802163,
        4.1993051,
        4.1565366,
        4.1757708,
        4.1794515,
        4.1604443,
        4.1763854,
        4.1305156
      ),
      loglabour1 = c(
        8.4269047,
        8.3201513,
        8.3074541,
        8.6718111,
        8.3564472,
        8.7928076,
        8.4286938,
        8.5548258,
        8.4670658,
        8.4601631,
        8.5880499,
        8.7033844,
        8.4163055,
        8.4609327,
        8.408637,
        8.2813377,
        8.5321655,
        8.748374,
        8.4074202,
        8.5465651,
        8.4499121,
        8.5398359,
        8.4387693,
        8.4273024,
        8.6929197,
        8.3125973,
        8.658803,
        8.4356194,
        8.5352049,
        8.6938343,
        8.4816732,
        8.4344358,
        8.859129,
        8.5064116,
        8.6129656,
        8.5548258,
        8.6129656,
        8.7033844,
        8.4286938,
        8.3125973,
        8.5465651,
        8.658803,
        8.5880499,
        8.6929197,
        8.4387693,
        8.4074202,
        8.748374,
        8.6938343,
        8.859129,
        8.6718111,
        8.4344358,
        8.4816732,
        8.5321655,
        8.4499121,
        8.3564472,
        8.5352049,
        8.3074541,
        8.7928076,
        8.3201513,
        8.4269047,
        8.2813377,
        8.4609327,
        8.4356194,
        8.4670658,
        8.5398359,
        8.408637,
        8.4163055,
        8.4601631,
        8.4273024,
        8.5064116
      ),
      loglabour2 = c(
        -1.3032292,-1.5044585,
        0.24194273,
        0.61871445,
        0.40313604,
        1.9860474,
        1.5840408,-1.7966279,
        0.21781437,-0.80343562,
        -0.7096265,-0.26014385,-1.052639,-2.1951094,
        0.52529126,-0.36803037,
        1.4018046,
        0.57941169,-0.63426656,-2.7012603,-0.6586107,
        0.12560239,
        -1.3962854,-0.93453068,
        2.2929618,-2.3867564,-0.3627651,
        0.14673021,
        1.1381592,-0.10424779,-2.3269727,-0.007220731,
        1.6822493,
        -2.2022393,-1.1601055,-1.7966279,-1.1601055,-0.26014385,
        1.5840408,-2.3867564,-2.7012603,-0.3627651,-0.7096265,
        2.2929618,
        -1.3962854,-0.63426656,
        0.57941169,-0.10424779,
        1.6822493,
        0.61871445,-0.007220731,-2.3269727,
        1.4018046,-0.6586107,
        0.40313604,
        1.1381592,
        0.24194273,
        1.9860474,-1.5044585,-1.3032292,
        -0.36803037,-2.1951094,
        0.14673021,
        0.21781437,
        0.12560239,
        0.52529126,-1.052639,-0.80343562,-0.93453068,-2.2022393
      ),
      loglabour3 = c(
        8.5716619,
        8.5822763,
        8.5671768,
        8.9138956,
        8.7382259,
        9.1257057,
        8.5623245,
        8.8020086,
        8.5572729,
        8.75842,
        9.0632677,
        9.0895538,
        8.5931168,
        8.8453484,
        8.5558758,
        8.9127951,
        9.0023937,
        8.9690628,
        8.4405375,
        8.9107132,
        8.7301798,
        8.8397036,
        8.6849604,
        8.6335611,
        8.8469181,
        8.5612812,
        9.0418806,
        8.5892353,
        8.9477854,
        9.0587311,
        8.6858816,
        8.6177435,
        9.1471338,
        8.7598467,
        8.8224411,
        8.8020086,
        8.8224411,
        9.0895538,
        8.5623245,
        8.5612812,
        8.9107132,
        9.0418806,
        9.0632677,
        8.8469181,
        8.6849604,
        8.4405375,
        8.9690628,
        9.0587311,
        9.1471338,
        8.9138956,
        8.6177435,
        8.6858816,
        9.0023937,
        8.7301798,
        8.7382259,
        8.9477854,
        8.5671768,
        9.1257057,
        8.5822763,
        8.5716619,
        8.9127951,
        8.8453484,
        8.5892353,
        8.5572729,
        8.8397036,
        8.5558758,
        8.5931168,
        8.75842,
        8.6335611,
        8.7598467
      ),
      loglabour4 = c(
        4.0981388,
        4.025712,
        4.0569224,
        4.0345945,
        4.1008277,
        3.9898756,
        3.9675186,
        4.204318,
        4.1024103,
        4.024951,
        4.0606198,
        4.0464692,
        4.0674639,
        4.0897164,
        4.0312428,
        4.0718594,
        4.1024852,
        4.2794919,
        4.1518111,
        4.1007166,
        4.1000609,
        4.0786386,
        4.0135407,
        4.1207833,
        4.0190663,
        4.0609179,
        4.0040684,
        4.1356573,
        4.0555511,
        4.0984778,
        4.190052,
        4.074995,
        3.9979038,
        4.0961123,
        4.1638103,
        4.204318,
        4.1638103,
        4.0464692,
        3.9675186,
        4.0609179,
        4.1007166,
        4.0040684,
        4.0606198,
        4.0190663,
        4.0135407,
        4.1518111,
        4.2794919,
        4.0984778,
        3.9979038,
        4.0345945,
        4.074995,
        4.190052,
        4.1024852,
        4.1000609,
        4.1008277,
        4.0555511,
        4.0569224,
        3.9898756,
        4.025712,
        4.0981388,
        4.0718594,
        4.0897164,
        4.1356573,
        4.1024103,
        4.0786386,
        4.0312428,
        4.0674639,
        4.024951,
        4.1207833,
        4.0961123
      ),
      logunem1 = c(
        4.3820267,
        5.7037826,
        5.480639,
        5.857933,
        5.2470241,
        5.2983174,
        6.0867748,
        5.4380794,
        4.8675346,
        5.521461,
        5.768321,
        5.5606818,
        5.6698809,
        5.0106354,
        5.0106354,
        5.2983174,
        4.7874918,
        5.3936276,
        5.1357985,
        4.7004805,
        5.2470241,
        5.5984221,
        6.1944056,
        4.8675346,
        6.0637851,
        5.5984221,
        5.4380794,
        4.9416423,
        5.1357985,
        5.3471074,
        4.3820267,
        5.7365723,
        5.6698809,
        5.7037826,
        4.7004805,
        5.4380794,
        4.7004805,
        5.5606818,
        6.0867748,
        5.5984221,
        4.7004805,
        5.4380794,
        5.768321,
        6.0637851,
        6.1944056,
        5.1357985,
        5.3936276,
        5.3471074,
        5.6698809,
        5.857933,
        5.7365723,
        4.3820267,
        4.7874918,
        5.2470241,
        5.2470241,
        5.1357985,
        5.480639,
        5.2983174,
        5.7037826,
        4.3820267,
        5.2983174,
        5.0106354,
        4.9416423,
        4.8675346,
        5.5984221,
        5.0106354,
        5.6698809,
        5.521461,
        4.8675346,
        5.7037826
      ),
      logroad = c(
        6.6024523,
        5.0807829,
        5.0434251,
        8.8258247,
        6.5759125,
        8.9816189,
        6.6368647,
        4.8805265,
        7.4716477,
        4.0638852,
        6.772737,
        8.1171637,
        6.2517114,
        6.9940248,
        6.6065149,
        7.3781962,
        6.9119463,
        7.727623,
        7.4472265,
        6.6843619,
        6.5839624,
        7.1206059,
        6.7319722,
        6.8847938,
        7.984633,
        3.3945084,
        5.8766146,
        4.9794884,
        6.8573036,
        6.4385514,
        3.246491,
        6.8694301,
        9.1673594,
        5.3494859,
        6.5704627,
        4.8805265,
        6.5704627,
        8.1171637,
        6.6368647,
        3.3945084,
        6.6843619,
        5.8766146,
        6.772737,
        7.984633,
        6.7319722,
        7.4472265,
        7.727623,
        6.4385514,
        9.1673594,
        8.8258247,
        6.8694301,
        3.246491,
        6.9119463,
        6.5839624,
        6.5759125,
        6.8573036,
        5.0434251,
        8.9816189,
        5.0807829,
        6.6024523,
        7.3781962,
        6.9940248,
        4.9794884,
        7.4716477,
        7.1206059,
        6.6065149,
        6.2517114,
        4.0638852,
        6.8847938,
        5.3494859
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -70L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

```







Here are my codes: 

`library(mlogit)
FDI <- dfidx(trimmed_data)
ml.FDI <- mlogit(choice ~ logPCI + logopenness + loglabour3 + logseaport3 +logunem1|logMAinside1 + logMAoutside1 + logSAinside1 + logSAoutside1,FDI , reflevel = "Hanoi_city")
summary(ml.FDI)
hl.FDI <- mlogit(choice ~ logPCI + logopenness + loglabour3 + logseaport3 +logunem1|logMAinside1 + logMAoutside1 + logSAinside1 + logSAoutside1,FDI , reflevel = "Hanoi_city", heterosc = TRUE)
``
````